# Can Gangplank's ultimate be reliably controlled?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I am playing pretty actively with [Gangplank](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gangplank) the last time (mainly because of his Remove Scurvy ability). But i have noticed that his ult is pretty unreliable. Yes you can use it cross map to steal baron or secure a kill or something but accuracy is a big issue. I have seen enemy champs just walk through the entire area (max upgraded) without even getting hit. I was wondering if there were area's where cannonballs hit more often or how to use this properly since in my opinion this is not the scariest anti-flee ability.

Comment: They actually pushed out a patch to make it more evenly distributed and random a long time ago - there's no part of the AoE that will reliably do damage when you need it. Center it on whatever you want to kill or put it along a path they will have to take.

Comment: years ago it was about twice the size, as well...  Aaaah, GP used to be soooo strong. :(

Comment: Much as @SirDuckDuck I feel you will receive better results if you use GP's ultimate for it's SLOW rather than it's DPS component. The Dmg is random, the slow is not. So if you keep this in mind, you'll always come out ahead, and even possibly more ahead than you expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's totally random. I tend to place it in areas that are congested, like tri-bush area in jungle, the paths close to the blue on each respective side, near the wraiths, wherever there's a teamfight.  Try to actively see where your jungler is, and use it when he ganks for easy assists.  Also if I plan on diving my enemy I place it between him and his path to his tower.

This is anecdotal, however in response to your OP, yes it is unreliable.

**EDIT:** you may or may not play these champions, but if you play Karthus, Soraka, or Shen, you should have a pretty good understanding of how to watch the mini-map and be a good global presence.  Use GP's Ult in similar situations that you'd use theirs. (I.E. try to secure kills or score a few easy assists, even if it doesn't turn the tide of the teamfight, you'll get cash if an enemy dies and you don't have to leave lane.)

Answer (score 3):

[Gankplanks](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gangplank) ult says:

> > 25 cannonballs randomly drop over the duration, each one dealing magic damage to enemies within a radius of 150(Radius of ult is 600).

So you can not be sure that you will hit the enemy with it.

I think his ult is better to be used for its slow since it can help your allies to catch up  or get away from an enemy while doing some additional damage.

In team fights I can be very handy since five enemy are in your ult range, your chances of hitting at least one is very high. This will also make it harder for them to escape.

Comment: But using an ult simply as a slow seems a little bit over the top doesn't it?

Comment: An ult that has unlimited casting range, A big area of affect, a slow **and** also does a lot of damage(With certainty) seems a bit over the top for me! But there are a few players that are lucky enough to walk to a GP ult without getting hit, so its not **simply** a slow

Answer (score 2):

No, Cannon Barrage drops 25 cannonballs randomly in the affected area. The chances of an enemy being able to walk through it unscathed, however, are pretty slim.

As far as anti-flee abilities go, however, it seems fairly reliable. I can think of only a couple that might be superior, and they have their own downsides.

1. Twisted Fate's Destiny: Can easily leave you stranded in enemy
   territory, isn't global.
2. Ashe's Enchanted Crystal Arrow, Lux's
   Final Spark, Draven's Whirling Death, Ezreal's Trueshot Barrage:
   Less Reliable due to only affecting a single line, Final Spark isn't
   global.
3. Pantheon's Grand Skyfall: Similar to Cannon Barrage, but also has Destiny's downsides.
4. Karthus' Requiem: very long cooldown

Comment: Grand Skyfall's huge casting animation time almost makes it a mini-teleport more than an ultimate, lol